# Conflicts during rebase never go away

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm seeing conflicts during `git rebase` when I don't expect any. I have

```
* - A   master
     \
      B - C - D - E   release
```

Now I do

```
% git checkout release
% get rebase master release

[...]
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in webserver/app/api/model/Move.scala
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0015 work in progress
[...]
```

but since `release` was branched off `master` and already has all it's commits (namely commit `A` why does rebase complain at all? I wouldn't expect the `release` branch to change at all.

Which part am I missing here?

Comment: Just a hint: `git rebase master release` is the same as `git checkout release && git rebase master`

Comment: I'm confused. This doesn't work as expected for me.

Comment: Is this code in a public repo? I'm interested in looking at what this can be.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't code I can share. I'm using merge in stead of rebase now, which "solves" the problem for now.

Comment: ok, but what does the graph look like when the merge has been done?

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
git rebase master
```

without the second parameter.

Comment: AFAIK, that wouldn't make any difference. If I'm on `release` then `git rebase master` is the same as `git rebase master release`. No?

Comment: Yes, `git rebase master` should be the same as `git rebase master release`. Actually, with the commit tree you have, that rebase command should be a no-op.